# Google Forms API - creating a watch: Error 400 Project does not have necessary OAuth permissions from authorizing user

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-forms

I am using the Node.js googleapis module to create a watch on a Google Form using the Forms API. I've done the following:

- Created an OAuth2 client
- Authorized a user with the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" scopes
- Created a Pub/Sub topic
- Added the Forms notification service account (forms-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com) as a "Pub/Sub Publisher" role on the topic

But I am still getting this error when trying to create a watch:

```
{
  message: 'Project does not have necessary OAuth permissions from authorizing user.',
  domain: 'global',
  reason: 'failedPrecondition'
}
```

Here is the code I am using to authorize and create the watch:

```
const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI)
auth.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN })

const forms = google.forms({ version: "v1", auth })
forms.forms.watches.create({
    formId: "1D5yqLRc6Thgi-F1xNANsbKve8iQzLA-qlZAKhY1ZyJ8",
    requestBody: {
        watch: {
            target: { topic: { topicName: `projects/${PROJECT}/topics/forms-submit` } },
            eventType: "RESPONSES"
        }
    }
})
```

I've verified that the refresh token is authorized for the intended scopes using the auth.getTokenInfo function. I'm also fairly certain it's not a scope issue, as I've tested without the correct scopes and I get a different error: 403 "Insufficient Permission". I also know that the authorized user has edit permissions on the Form, because when that's not the case, the error is: 403 "The caller does not have permission".

I've done some research on StackOverflow and the Google forums, but it seems this issue is only replicated when people are trying to create a watch with Service Account authorization, and it's fixed when they switch to OAuth2.

I should also note that my OAuth2 client is setup properly and authorized, as I can interact with other APIs (Gmail, Sheets, etc.) and I can even use other Forms endpoints (tested with forms.watches.list).